# How to make Page Visibility API working in Scala.js?

Tags: scala, scala.js

I want to use the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) in Scala.js. I noticed that there's already a facade implemented so I tried to reuse it like that:

```
dom.document.visibilitychange = (e: Event) => {
   println(s"Hidden ${dom.document.hidden}.")
}
```

I tried it with Safari 10.1, Firefox 53.0.2 and Chrome 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit) on Mac but I do not get the output in my console. 
I tried [Mozilla's live example](http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/) and it works perfectly so I am probably doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the spec `document.visibilityState` is read only. Try using the following instead:

```
def h(e: Event): Unit = ???
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", h _, false)
```